# SMTP "Failure sending mail" exception after deploy, works well with localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

Using the tutorial in this link [How to Implement Contact Us Page in ASP.NET MVC (ASP.NET 5 )](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1081578/How-to-Implement-Contact-Us-Page-in-ASP-NET-MVC-AS). I managed to get my application send email to my gmail account. However, it is failing after publish and gives "Failure sending mail" error. I have done the possible fixes which you can see below but didn't help. Thank you.

Here is my HomeController code:

```
public ActionResult Contact(Contact c)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("example1@gmail.com");
                msg.To.Add("example1@gmail.com");
                msg.Subject = c.Subject;
                //msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
                sb.Append("<b>First name: </b>" + c.FirstName + "<br/><br/>");
                sb.Append("<b>Last name: </b>" + c.LastName + "<br/><br/>");
                sb.Append("<b>Email: </b>" + c.Email + "<br/><br/>");
                sb.Append("<b>Phone: </b>" + c.PhoneNumber + "<br/><br/>");
                sb.Append("<b>Message: </b>" + c.Message + "<br/><br/>");
                msg.Body = sb.ToString();
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                // We use gmail as our smtp client
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(); 
                smtpClient.Send(msg);
                msg.Dispose();
                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.ContactMessage = "Your Message has been sent. Thank you for Contacting us. ";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.ContactMessage = $" Sorry we are facing the following Problem: {ex.Message}";
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And my Web.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethode="Network">
            <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port"587" userName="***" password="***" enableSsl="true"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: **NOTE**: never, ever, publish live credentials on the web !!! Plus, there are so many free SMTP services, why would you use Google mail with all there policies? Try [Sparkpost](https://www.sparkpost.com/) or [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) both free up to 10.000 emails a month

Comment: My bad, Thats was by mistake. So is the problem because m using google?

Comment: Google has so many restrictions, I had, some years ago a way to send emails as SMTP, but soon realized wasn't that stable and I moved on to services that actually were built for this... you have several, just choose one, and nowdays the offers is amazing, since Amazon SES (62k emails a month free) to Postmark, SendGrid, AuthMailer... and so many more...

Comment: Guess the problem is not google since i changed to my domain email and the results are same. It sends message to my domain email when debugging in LocalHost but same error after i publish.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly then here is your scenario.

1. When you use same credential locally it is working.
2. Same credential after publish it is not working.
   Is this issue of google ? Yes. 
   Reason: It seems that your publish server is located some where else. So when you put site over there gmail assume that somebody try to access gmail from another location.

   Solution: Your account will receive one email stating that is that really you that trying to access account ? Allow permission over there. It might works. As I have faced same issue and it solve after that.

Comment: Hi, yes thats the case but i am not receiving the permission email from google. I have tried many times.

Comment: Check all tab in Gmail.

Comment: I checked all its not there and now have changed to my domain email and the results are same. It sends message to my domain email when debugging in LocalHost but same error after i publish.

Answer (score 0):

Not a precise solution to the problem but.I changed to my domain email, changed the SMTP port to 80 and removed enableSsl now it works.